# How to UI test a Cocoa Touch Framework?

Tags: swift, xcode8, xcode-ui-testing, cocoa-touch

What is the best practice for UI testing a Cocoa Touch Framework that contains UI helper methods and extensions?

I was thinking of adding a new iOS project to it as well as a UI test project and having them built and ran only within the ProjectTests scheme. Is this how it's done? I can't find much documentation about this.

Comment: check this repository for UI-Testing https://github.com/joemasilotti/UI-Testing-Cheat-Sheet I think that it helpful to use UITest

Comment: @SwiftyCruz Thanks. I know how to UI test. My question is what is the best practice for UI testing a framework.

Comment: What do you mean when you say a cocoa touch framework? Do you have an app to run?

Comment: @Oletha No. No app to run. It's a framework containing helper methods for UIKit (like for example, one that pushes the views up when the keyboard appears).

Comment: Surely you can't UI test when there's no app?

Comment: @Oletha _That is exactly my question_: how do you test UI helper methods in a framework? Should one add a UI mock project? Are you familiar with the concept of framework?